# Why isn't width changed on hover state in this snippet

Tags: jquery, css

The background position and prepend are working fine but the width of the hovered over element is not receiving the new width with the routine below. I think I have tried all permutations of syntax except the right one! Unless, for whatever reason, the width of an Li cannot be changed in this way?

I even tried just setting the css with css('width','128) and that wouldn't work ...thinking something with animating was causing an issue..but I'm stumped.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initwidth = $("li").width(); // updated

    // hover in
    $(".qnav li").hover( 
       function(){

           // start the animation
           $(this).stop().animate({width: "128"},{queue:false, duration:"fast" });
           $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "0 -30px"},{queue:false, duration:"fast" });
           $(this).prepend('<span class="prepended">Question </span');

       // hover out
       },function(){
           $(this).stop().animate({width: initwidth});
           $(this).stop().animate({backgroundPosition: "0 0"},{queue:false, duration:"fast" });

           $(".prepended").remove();

       }
    );
});
```

The css on the element is:

```
.qnav li{
   display: block;
   float: left;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 2;
   width:38px;
   padding: 0;
   background:#aaa9a9 url(images/arrowSprite.png) no-repeat 0 0;
}
```

Comment: not the answer but please change initwidth = $("li").width(); to var initwidth = $("li").width();

Comment: Not sure if it's required, but have you tried adding "px"? Like: `width: "128px"`.

Comment: Please open a jsfiddle or jsbin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the `.stop()` part :) It does the trick for me: http://jsfiddle.net/skip405/Qjks9/

Besides caching the `$(this)`, [as suggested in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269923/1144057) I would recommend to be a bit more specific in making the variable as well)

So instead of `var initwidth = $("li").width();` try using `var initwidth = $("ul.qnav li").width();` or something of the kind. Otherwise when there are two or more lists both ordered and unordered who knows what might happen to your animation ;)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to copy/paste that and set it up/solve in jsfiddle...I see where I was stubbing my mouse!

Answer (score 0):

1- you are missing the "px" on the width attribute:

```
$(this).stop().animate({width: "128px"},{queue:false, duration:"fast" });
```

2- you are missing the closing `>` tag on the `span`:

```
$(this).prepend('<span class="prepended">Question </span>');
```

3- chain you methods and use cached instances for calling jQuery methods:

```
var $this = $(this);

$this.stop().animate({width: "128"},{queue:false, duration:"fast" })
       .animate({backgroundPosition: "0 -30px"},{queue:false, duration:"fast" })
       .prepend('<span class="prepended">Question </span>');
```

This optimize the performance, since jQuery will not to process the object on every call;

Comment: hmm... I didn't think "px" was needed as seen here:(though I tried that as well as single versus double quotes) http://api.jquery.com/animate/
however, yikes on closing the span! I'll look this over when I'm back. I'm beginning to think using natural block elements, ie a div in this case will allow a hidden span to take its space when shown and therefore, no calculations will be needed. Thanks all!